# What shell does Jenkins use?

Tags: jenkins

What shell is used in Jenkins when calling the `shell` command? I'm running Jenkins on a Linux machine.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

From the help/question mark icon of the "Execute shell" section:

> Runs a shell script (defaults to sh, but this is configurable) for
>   building the project.

If you go to Manage Jenkins  --> Configure System you will find an option (called "Shell executable") to set the name or absolute path to the shell that you want your shell scripts to use...

For my system without configuring this option... it uses bash!

Comment: Hmm, I'm not seeing this in current version of Jenkins :(

Comment: I see default shell with a jenkins 2.7.4 on CentOS 7.1 is bash (sh on OS is bash), default shell with a jenkins 2.32.1 on Debian 8 docker container is dash (sh on OS is dash).

Comment: There is a way to change default shell interpreter directly in the Jenkinsfile pipeline script: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/215171038-How-do-I-run-a-different-Shell-interpreter-in-a-Pipeline-Script-

Comment: Thank you!  I was adding #!/bin/bash to the top of my Jenkins scripts so I could use BASH array syntax and that was causing subtle and incomprehensible errors in the build

Answer (score 33):

Simply declare your shell on the first line of your script as you do in any shell script file:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: This do not work.
Shell used is always the default shell of the *nix user who starts the process.

Comment: This works for me, using a recent version of Jenkins as of 2016/05.

Comment: @JohnMcGehee What version of jenkins did you use?

Comment: Beware that a space is not allowed after the #!

Comment: @PabloJomer I am using Jenkins 1.625.3

Comment: that does work for me. in Execute shell or ScriptTrigger. I* use '#!/bin/bash -ex'

Comment: This only works in *steps*, not e.g. in *environment* if you have an assignment like `no_proxy = "${sh(script:'echo 172.2{0..9}.0.{21..27} | sed \"s/ /,/g\"', returnStdout: true).trim()}"` that only works in bash

Answer (score 14):

Jenkins by default looks for `sh` in the `PATH` environment variable, however the result (e.g. `/bin/sh`) may point to different shells. For example, on Ubuntu 6.10 or later, `/bin/sh` is a symlink to Dash.

So for the question "what shell is used in Jenkins ...", it depends. To avoid the uncertainty, you can: (take Bash as an example)

1. Explicitly configure shell executable in Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Shell > Shell executable, e.g., `/bin/bash`. (system-wide configuration)
2. Use shebang line to specify the interpreter should be used, e.g., `#!/usr/bin/env bash` (specific to a job)

Comment: Great answer,it help me a lot!

Answer (score 8):

You can set the default shell using *Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Shell executable*.

For jobs that use a shell different from the default, begin the *Execute shell* build step with a shebang, such as:

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh -e -x

command1
command2
   ...
```

You can even use `/usr/bin/env` to use, say, Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

**Beware that a space is not allowed** after the `#!`:

```
#! /usr/bin/tcsh    # Wrong
```

This will give the error,

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ""
```

I tested the above on Jenkins 1.625.3

Comment: Essentially the same answer as the accepted one, posted 4 years later.

Answer (score 7):

I tried printing the env by adding the following shell command to my Jenkins build.

```
env
```

The output showed that the SHELL was set to `tcsh` for my instance.

Comment: $SHELL is notoriously unreliable.  Try:
ps -p $$