# $BUILD_USER not expanded in Jenkins email notification

Tags: email, github, jenkins

We use Email Notification plugin as the last build step. When the build is started manually in Jenkins, the $BUILD_USER will expanded properly and show the user name who starts the build. But when the build is triggered automatically by a new commit in GitHub, it shows like this? How can I fix this?

```
Build Status : Fixed
Build Cause : MANUALTRIGGER
Build user : $BUILD_USER 
Build User ID: $BUILD_USER_ID 
Build Number : 57
Build Id : 57
```

Comment: Check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36213488/3623345) answer helps you out. Reason is, on non-git-triggered builds these vars dont get populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable wasn't there by default, it requires a new plugin: 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin