# Jenkins Java: Get user who started the build

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Under `http://[JENKINS_NAME]/job/[JOB_NAME]/[BUILD_NUMBER]/`

I can see **Started by user [USER_NAME]**.

I want to get that username from my java application.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what version of jenkins are you using?

Comment: can your java program can take input params? How are you running? If you can say that, I can enhance my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a http call to get all these details. URL to get those details is:

```
http://<Jenkins URL>/job/<job name>/<build number>/api/json
```

After the rest call, you will be getting this json.

```
{
"_class": "hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild",
"actions": [
    {
        "_class": "hudson.model.CauseAction",
        "causes": [
            {
                "_class": "hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause",
                "shortDescription": "Started by user XXXXXX",
                "userId": "xxx@yyy.com",
                "userName": "ZZZZZZZZ"
            }
        ]
    },
    {},
    {
        "_class": "jenkins.metrics.impl.TimeInQueueAction"
    },
    {},
    {}
],
...
}
```

So All you have do is parse this json and get the value under `javavar['actions'][0]['causes'][0]['userName']`. Definitely it will be like that only. I maynot be sure about the indexes. You just try and figure out. Hope this helps.

Mostly for every page in the jenkins instance, you will be having `REST API` link. Please click on it to see the rest api url and its output for that url.

Comment: This is the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could get the build user from Jenkins environment (i.e as an env var). If you use Jenkins 2 pipeline, For example:
pipeline {

```
 //rest of the pipeline
 stages {
   stage('Build Info') {
     steps {
       wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
        sh 'java -jar <your_java_app>.jar'
       }
     } 
   }
 }
```

In your java app you should be able to get the environment variable using `System.getenv("BUILD_USER")` or else you could pass it as a JVM arg. Ex: `sh 'java -jar -DbuildUser=$BUILD_USER <your_java_app>.jar'` and get the buildUser system property in the application.

On older version of Jenkins, you may use Build User Vars Plugin or Env Inject plugin. As in the answers on this question. [how to get the BUILD_USER in Jenkins when job triggered by timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36194316/how-to-get-the-build-user-in-jenkins-when-job-triggered-by-timer)

Comment: The question is get the username via api

Comment: the question is to get the user name via api not within the pipeline script.

Comment: That's your assumption, where does the OP say that? Also, even though this doesn't use the API, it works and useful. What do you gain from downvoting?