# Display Username of pipeline builds on UI

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm new users of Jenkins, I would like to add in the stage UI, some informations on each build as git branch, and the user who lunched the build. any ideas please ? I thought of adding a new stage in the pipeline script but did not know how to print the UI view.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the branch name via `env.BRANCH_NAME`, however, it seems that retrieving the user who kicked off the build is a little more complicated, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36545353/616436

With regards displaying the information, you can use `currentBuild.description = "Build info here..."` to display a message in the Build History of Jenkins e.g.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you call a stage step with the *stage ()* call, you can give as input value the name of the stage. For example, you can do *stage ('my own name')* or *stage ('another different name')*. Just notice a few things:

- As input, you can use variables. I have not tested, but I assume these variables should be "global" to be used. You can modify the variable adding what you need and then, use it in the *stage ()* call
- If you change the stage name between builds, jenkins job will show just the stages of the last build, not the previous ones because you have "different" stages!
- There are other solutions, like adding that information you want into the build description/title or using plugins like the "Rich Text Publisher"