# Jenkins Mailer - Send e-mail to user who started build job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-mailer-plugin

When a build job fails, I want to send an email to the user who started the job.

I use a jenkins buildfile (Pipeline script). The current code is:

```
     post {
          success {
              doSomething()
          }
          failure {
              step([$class: 'Mailer', notifyEveryUnstableBuild: true, recipients: 'me@foo', sendToIndividuals: true])
          }
          changed {
              step([$class: 'Mailer', notifyEveryUnstableBuild: true, recipients: 'me@foo', sendToIndividuals: true])
          }
      }
```

Sending the mail to me@foo "statically" (i.e. putting the address as in the code above) works well. So the Mailer plugin works well, but I cannot figure out how to make a reference to the user that started the job.

I tried out putting s.th. like the following at the recipients list, but it does not work: '${BUILD_USER_EMAIL}', $BUILD_USER_EMAIL

Thank you in advance for any hint to solve this.

Comment: Hello @gabolo. Check this solution. Try method 3.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60440626/10363259

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the BUILD\_USER in Jenkins when job triggered by timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36194316/how-to-get-the-build-user-in-jenkins-when-job-triggered-by-timer)

Answer (score 0):

We identified the problem by ourselves: the plugin [**build user vars**](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-user-vars-plugin/) was not activated correctly. Now it works.

We use the following code:

```
pipeline {
  ...
  post {
    failure {
      step([$class: 'Mailer', notifyEveryUnstableBuild: true, recipients: "${BUILD_USER_EMAIL}", sendToIndividuals: true])
    }
    changed {
      step([$class: 'Mailer', notifyEveryUnstableBuild: true, recipients: "${BUILD_USER_EMAIL}", sendToIndividuals: true])
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for your replies.