# bash string manipulation got errors in jenkins shell (not pipeline)

Tags: linux, string, bash, jenkins

i am trying to get value of variable by given string:
Running this code on Jenkins  and its get "bad substitution"
in regular shell it works.
example:

```
param1="hello"
param2="world"
PARAMS="param1 param2"
for p in $PARAMS;do
        echo ${!p}" "
done
```

what the best way to make it work in Jenkins too.

Comment: Please confirm that you are using `bash` and not some other shell. I have a feeling that jenkins calls `sh` instead of `bash`. Add the command `ps` to the top of your script and show us the output.

Comment: Further to @Socowi's remarks, add `#!/bin/bash`  to the first line to force a bash shell. ps: works for my Jenkins instance, but I don't think it achieves what you expect; `${!p}" "` is the same effect as `"${p} "`. `${!p*}` is different. Odd [Parameter substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PARAMSUBREF)

Comment: i am using bash. i think the problem is that Jenkins try to parse/switch it and when it got ! it fail.

Comment: @IanW As far as I know the `#! ...` is ignored by jenkins. See [What shell does Jenkins use?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12457930/6770384). Also, `${!p}" "` is **neither** the same as `"${p} "` **nor** `${!p*}` – OP is using *indirection*, see the official bash manual or [this site](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Evaluating_indirect.2Freference_variables).

Comment: @MatanRamrazker Did you really confirm that you are using bash? I don't think so. Anyways, you could try to save your script in `/some/dir/myScript.sh`, prefix it with `#! /bin/bash`, make it executable, and only call `/some/dir/myScript.sh` in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

You must use with $ sign before the name of the variable:

```
PARAMS="$param1 $param2"
for p in $PARAMS;do
        echo ${p}" "
done
```

Comment: That won't work when the variable value contains whitespace