# Jenkins rsync excludes do not exclude any files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins, rsync

I've got a Jenkins server running with some pipelines. I wanted to move from copying a tar file to a web server (and extracting it there) to synching the files with rsync. This works fine, but if I define an excluded file or folder, it is still synched.
I have this line in my Jenkinsfile:

```bash
sh "rsync -av --dry-run --exclude={build.sh,run.sh} . ${SERVER_USER}@${SERVER}:${SERVER_DIRECTORY}"
```

As reference: these are the contents of ".":

```bash
$ tree src/
src/
├── build.sh
├── foo.bar
├── run.sh
└── var

1 directory, 3 files
```

And the contents of `SERVER_DIRECTORY`:

```bash
$ tree .
.
└── public
    └── index.php

1 directory, 1 file
```

If I run the command from above manually, then I get an incremental file list without the files `build.sh` and `run.sh`. On Jenkins they both appear in this file list:

```bash
[Pipeline] sh
+ rsync -av --dry-run --exclude={build.sh,run.sh} . deploy_user@webserver.local:/srv/apache/projects/test
sending incremental file list
./
build.sh
foo.bar
run.sh
var/
```

What I tried so far:

- using a trailing slash at the end of ".", so instead I used "./", since the man page states that this leads to creation of the directory at the destination path
- using a trailing slash at the end of `SERVER_DIRECTORY`
- comparing rsync versions, path to rsync binaries and environments, but the shells are the same and versions and paths also

```bash
// in Jenkinsfile:
sh "echo $SHELL"

// Output on Jenkins:
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo /bin/bash
/bin/bash
```

- did the whole rsync process manually: logged into Jenkins with jenkins user, go to build folder and run rsync command (worked as expected)

I tried it with "single excludes", meaning "--exclude build.sh --exclude run.sh", which worked, but I' curious, why the other solution only works when run manually, but not via Jenkins. Is this some kind of escaping issue or what am I missing here?

I hope that someone can help me on this and I'm looking forward to every anwser! :)

**Edit #1**: I got the same behaviour when I tried `mkdir {foo,bar}`: Jenkins creates one folder

```bash
[Pipeline] sh
+ mkdir {foo,bar}
[Pipeline] sh
+ ls -la
total 1504
drwxr-xr-x   2 jenkins jenkins   4096 Sep  5 14:26 {foo,bar}
```

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73610868/different-outcome-executing-commands-on-host-manually-vs-jenkins-pipeline) could be related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it now by setting *Jenkins* > *Manage Jenkins* > *Configure System* > *Shell executable* to `/bin/bash` as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455932/what-shell-does-jenkins-use).

I'm not sure, why the answer of @ycr didn't work for me, since this solution obviously works for other people.

Answer (score 1):

`x={a,b}` syntax is not something specific to `rsync` and it's something available in `Bash`.

For example, if you execute the following in `bash`.

```
echo --exclude={run.sh,deploy.sh}
```

You will see the following output.

```
--exclude=run.sh --exclude=deploy.sh
```

Jenkins executes shell commands using the default Shell using `sh -c ....` hence some of the Bash stuff will not work. In order to get around this set the Shebang line to point to `bash`, before executing the script.

```
sh"""
#!/bin/bash
rsync -av --dry-run --exclude={build.sh,run.sh} . ${SERVER_USER}@${SERVER}:${SERVER_DIRECTORY}
"""
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I understand now that it's something bash related. I tried that exact snippet of yours (copied it), but Jenkins still gives me the same output as above.