# Different outcome executing commands on host manually vs jenkins pipeline

Tags: bash, git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to git add & git commit files with a Jenkins pipeline. The problem is that when I execute commands manually on host I get a different results than those via my jenkinsfile.

When I execute whichever of the following:

```
git add './*/some_dir/sub_dir/*'
git add ./*/some_dir/sub_dir/*
git add */some_dir/sub_dir/*
```

I get the exact list of files that I want to push.
The same command in jenkinsfile adds all the files from working directory. I've already tried a different command like (with the same result as above):

```
find . -path '*/some_dir/sub_dir/*' | xargs git add
```

As well as a completely opposite approach:

```
git add . 
find . ! -path '*/some_dir/sub_dir/*' | xargs git reset
```

This on the other hand removes all added files and there is nothing to commit (while it of course works fine executed manually, leaving only those files that I want to push).

Do you have any clue why that is?

Comment: I guess the single quotes in the first `git add` are accidental and not actually in the command you tried?

Comment: @Jay, actually they are not. I've tried different options, while each works as desired when executed manually and it does not with jenkinsfile. I've edited the post with the commands I've tried.

Comment: Isolate the problem first. Run `find . ! -path '*/some_dir/sub_dir/*'` both manually and via jenkinsfile, see if their outputs differ and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Jenkins tends to be a pain in the <insert body part>, in part because jenkinsfiles use Groovy, which is rather gratuitously different from shell. That may not be the problem here but it's always annoying.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was the command I used before 'git add' to create a new empty branch:

```
git checkout --orphan temp_branch
```

When I checked with 'git status' all the files from working directory were already ready for commit. Yet I still don't understand why a newly created empty branch should already have all the files from working directory added.

Comment: There's no such thing as an *empty branch:* what `--orphan` does is create an *unborn branch* (or "orphan branch"; Git is inconsistent about what it calls this). But `git checkout --orphan` does not erase index or working tree, while `git switch --orphan` does. Be careful with both of these: they usually don't do what people expect, regardless of who the person is and what they expect.

Comment: That's educational. Thanks! What I needed actually was a local branch that I could add to only some of the files existing in some other pulled branch. Then push those selected files to a remote branch. I assumed I cannot execute 'checkout' as it would add the same files to my new branch that I already had in the already existing one

Comment: Switching branches (`git checkout` or `git switch` yanks out of your working tree, and Git's index, those files that don't belong in the commit you're moving *to*, and puts in, instead, the files that *do* belong in the commit you're moving to. So now you're on the other branch, using the files from that branch's tip commit. There's a caveat here that if you have modified some working tree and/or index copies, Git won't be able to switch branches, or will leave the modified files in place, whichever works for Git. Use `git worktree add` to create an additional working tree instead.

Comment: Doing any of this *inside Jenkins* is a little bit fraught, since Jenkins tends to run in a VM or Docker instance on a virtualized system with funky conditions, plus that whole annoying Groovy thing. A bunch of Unix/Linux basic assumptions get violated. I hate Jenkins.