# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline - Activating python venv

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, python-venv

I'm using declarative pipeline for jenkins and my goal is to have a separated virtual environment for each project in jenkins/workspace. I've created a new pipeline with the following code:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Pull all changes') {
            steps {
                git branch: "master", url: "git@fancylink.git"
            }
        }
        stage('Create and Activate venv') {
            steps {
                sh 'python3.11 -m venv venv'
                sh 'source venv/bin/activate'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            sh 'deactivate' 
        }
    }
}
```

However I'm getting this error:
[image]

When I try to do the same steps via SSH everything is working fine and venv is activated. Also I don't know if it's important but I have 2 version of the python on the server (python3.9, python3.11)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [source command not found in sh shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702425/source-command-not-found-in-sh-shell)

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455932/what-shell-does-jenkins-use

Comment: See this for running bash commands: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330148/run-bash-command-on-jenkins-pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Availability of `source` depends on the actual shell jenkins uses.  As mentioned in the comments, you probably should use `.` instead of `source`.

However;  activation and deactivation of venv is related to the scope of `sh`.

If you have multiple steps and multiple `sh`'s you need to activate the venv for each of those where you need to access python libs/tools installed into venv. This is because activation is applied the current shell and if you activate it on one `sh`, once that stops, venv settings are automatically deactivated because next `sh` will spawn a new shell.